# Accessing views with absolute paths on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, path

I'm trying to access a view in this way:

```
return View(@"~\Items\Details.aspx");
```

and I get this error:

> The view '~\Items\Details.aspx' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
>   ~\Items\Details.aspx

On the ItemsController, in the Details action, returning View() works just fine. Why can't I access that view from another controller?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Prefix it with '/Views' should help.

```
return View("~/Views/Items/Details.aspx");
```

Comment: I ran into this today, used this suggestion but also needed to add the ".cshtml" extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Items view a shared one (you put it in the Views/Shared folder), then you can just call View("Items") and it will work.

Comment: Actually, you can. It's not a good design IMHO, but it does work.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it in the meanwhile, because I noticed I was wrong: I was suggesting that you could not call views by absolute path.