# Return MVC View that matches Param File Name in Parent Folder and Sub-Folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to return an MVC view based on the filename passed into the controller function. However, the following requires a relative path:

```
[Route("/ReturnViewByFileName/{ViewName}")]
public ActionResult ReturnViewByFileName(string FileName)
{
    return View("~/RelativePath");
}
```

Since I want to find a view file that is based on the parameter file name and I want to search a particular folder and sub folders for that file name.

```
var path = CurrentEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\Views\Parentfolder";

string[] FindFile = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + FileName + 
"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The problem is, this gives you the full file path of the file and not the relative file path that View() requires.

Is there a simple way to do one of the following:

1. Override the View() function to accept a full file path
2. Convert a full file path name to a relative file path
3. Or something else I am overlooking

   **Solution**

   ```
   public ActionResult FindMVCView(string FileName)
   {
   var path = CurrentEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\ParentFolder";

   string[] FindFile = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + FileName +
   "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

   var newpath = FindFile[0].Replace(CurrentEnvironment.ContentRootPath, 
   "~/").Replace(@"\", "/");
   }
   ```

Comment: The view file is inside your project or not? I think the answer is yes, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421854/accessing-views-with-absolute-paths-on-asp-net-mvc You don't have to pass the full path in, just use it starting from ~/Views/xxxx.

Comment: Yes but I have to shape the path string from System.IO into the relative path string for View(). Which is option 2. I was hoping there was an in-build function to do this.

Comment: Okay, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path

Comment: That works. path.Replace(CurrentEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "~/").Replace(@"\", "/");